# How to use Selenium RC to verify contents of a japanese or french website?

Tags: java, selenium

I've to test a Japanese and french website using selenium RC with java eclipse. Here I've to get some text from website and to match it with the text stored in excel (both texts are in Japanese/french).
I'm using gettext() method but it is returning garbage value similarly in getting text from excel also.

Answer (score 0):

You've given us very little information to go on, bit it sounds like you've got problems with character sets and character encodings.  It is difficult to know what the precise cause is, but it may be that your "default" characterset is an 8-bit characterset, and that is what Selenium is using.  Try changing your locale settings so that UTF-8 is the default character set for Java.